# JQuery - new Date formatting and creating a var variable inside an array's option

Tags: jquery, date-formatting

I am trying to format a date object by first assigning it to a variable and then using the method `.format()` to convert it to the preferred format in a single line of an array's option in JQuery.

Here's the code I'm dealing with :

```
{
    id : function()
    {
        var starttime = Date($('#apptStartTime').val());
        var endtime = Date($('#apptEndTime').val());
        return $('#eventTitle').val()+starttime.format('YYYY-MM-DD'+'T'+'HH:mm'+':00')+endtime.format('YYYY-MM-DD'+'T'+'HH:mm'+':00');
    }
    title: $('#eventTitle').val(),
    start: new Date($('#apptStartTime').val()),
    end: new Date($('#apptEndTime').val())
}
```

As you can see in the id `option`, I'm trying to format the `Date($('#apptStartTime').val()` but it fails and the id option has an empty value.

When I attempted with :

```
    id : $('#eventTitle').val() + new Date($('#apptStartTime').val()) + new Date($('#apptEndTime').val()),
```

I get id : `BlaBlaMon Jul 17 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Standard Time)Tue Jul 18 2017 10:23:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Standard Time)`

However, I want to get  id : **`BlaBla2017-07-17T00:00:002017-07-18T10:23:00`**.

Comment: Is `id` supposed to be a function that you call, or a property that you set one time when creating the object?

Comment: There's no `.format()` method in Javascript `Date` objects.

Comment: Maybe you meant to use moment.js?

Comment: @Barmar In fact, id is supposed to be a property. Do you have any proposal then?

Comment: Use moment.js, it has the formatting function you want.

Comment: `'YYYY-MM-DD'+'T'+'HH:mm'+':00'` could just be `'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:00'`. What's the point of all the separate strings? This isn't a fix, just an observation of a weird pointless bit of code.

Comment: looking at `var starttime = Date(...` -  is `Date` a function of your own, or from a plugin? AFAIK there's no native JS function of that name, and you're not using `new` which would construct a new JS Date object. What does this function return?

Comment: As another side observation, I'd say trying to construct an ID from other properties of the object is a bad idea, unless you can guarantee those properties will never change in future. Firstly there's no guarantee that the values would be unique, unless your application enforces that separately, and secondly if the title or dates are changed in future, the ID based on the old values looks wrong and could cause confusion. Conversely if you allow the ID to change along with the properties, there's no point having an ID. Why not use an ID autogenerated by a database?

Comment: @ADyson Yes. you're right. How do I create a column ID that autogenerates through the database using MSSQL 2008

Comment: @Andrew by setting the (integer) primary key column of your table as an IDENTITY column. You can do it through the GUI in most SQL clients, or you can google the SQL command line syntax easily. (Whenever you insert a row you can then fetch the last generated row ID and return it to your application, if necessary, to associate it with the newly inserted data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar), the recommended way to deal with such case is to use **moment.js** and included it in the header of your html document.

Also, there was no need to make `id` a function call, you could simply do as follows:

```
    id : $('#eventTitle').val() + moment(new Date($('#apptStartTime').val())).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:00') + moment(new Date($('#apptEndTime').val())).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:00'),
```